# Как двигать несколько соседних элементов при нажатии на один из них js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на первый элемент, сдвигались на место все, стоящие за ним.
[image: Передвигаемые фишки]
А если двигать из начального положения, то нужно чтобы каждая следующая фишка двигала все предыдущие. например, если двигать вторую сразу, то вместе с ней должна сдвинуться и первая (сразу две):
[image: Начальное положение фишек]
Пока что "фишки" могут только перемещаться влево и обратно на своё место каждая:

```js
fishka1_1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fishka1_1.classList.toggle("fishka1_1-final")
    fishka1_1.classList.toggle("fishka1_1-initial")
  })

fishka1_2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fishka1_2.classList.toggle("fishka1_2-final")
  fishka1_2.classList.toggle("fishka1_2-initial")
})

fishka1_3.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fishka1_3.classList.toggle("fishka1_3-final")
  fishka1_3.classList.toggle("fishka1_3-initial")
})

fishka1_4.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fishka1_4.classList.toggle("fishka1_4-final")
  fishka1_4.classList.toggle("fishka1_4-initial")
})

fishka1_5.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fishka1_5.classList.toggle("fishka1_5-final")
  fishka1_5.classList.toggle("fishka1_5-initial")
})

fishka1_6.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fishka1_6.classList.toggle("fishka1_6-final")
  fishka1_6.classList.toggle("fishka1_6-initial")
})

fishka1_7.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fishka1_7.classList.toggle("fishka1_7-final")
  fishka1_7.classList.toggle("fishka1_7-initial")
})

fishka1_8.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fishka1_8.classList.toggle("fishka1_8-final")
  fishka1_8.classList.toggle("fishka1_8-initial")
})

fishka1_9.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fishka1_9.classList.toggle("fishka1_9-final")
  fishka1_9.classList.toggle("fishka1_9-initial")
})

fishka1_10.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fishka1_10.classList.toggle("fishka1_10-final")
    fishka1_10.classList.toggle("fishka1_10-initial")
  })
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 58px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {
  padding-top: 113px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1000%;
  width: 781.13px;
  height: 933.96px;
  /*    max-width: 781.13px;
    min-width: 933.96px;*/
  /*позиционирование по центру*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: block;
}

.pole {
  background: url('../img/1.svg') no-repeat center top / cover;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1052.83px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.str_1 {
  margin-top: -12px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_2 {
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_3 {
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_4 {
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_5 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_6 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_7 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_8 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_9 {
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.str_10 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fishka {
  overflow: auto;
}

.fishka:hover {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.fishka1_1-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_1-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_2-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_2-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_3-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_3-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_4-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_4-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_5-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_5-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_6-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_6-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_7-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_7-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_8-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_8-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_9-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_9-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.fishka1_10-initial {
  /* Стили, определяющие начальное положение
    элемента на странице, например: */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.fishka1_10-final {
  /* Стили, определяющие конечное положение, например: */
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.."></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="pole" class="pole">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="str_1">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka1_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_2">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka2_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_3">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka3_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_4">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka4_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_5">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka5_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_6">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka6_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_7">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka7_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_8">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka8_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_9">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_1" style="position: relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_2" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka9_10" onclick="">
      </div>

      <div class="str_10">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_1" style="position:  relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_2" style="position: relative; margin-right: 0px" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_3" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_4" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_5" onclick="">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_6" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_7" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_8" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_9" onclick="">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka" id="fishka10_10" onclick="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста вставьте ваш минимальный вопроизводимый код, нажав на кнопку Править под вопросом, далее в редакторе вопроса нужно нажать на CTRL+M и расстваить свой код по нужным блокам. Перед тем как вставить в сообщение, пожалуйста, убедитесь что код запускается корректно, всё отображается как вам надо и нет никаких ошибок

Comment: Код добавила, он работает, но не отображается поле потому что не могу добавить элементы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужен был функционал, как в обычной счётной доске

Рефакторинг:

- Уменьшил количество рядов (большее количество не имеет смысла, чтобы продемонстрировать алгоритм)
- Избавился от ненужных аттрибутов (большее количество не имеет смысла, чтобы продемонстрировать алгоритм)
- Убрал 100500 классов под каждый случай жизни, и заменил их 1 классом
- Убрал 100500 слушателей для каждого элемента
- Поменял некоторые названия

Логика:

- Для начала индексируем все фишки в каждом ряду отдельно
- Далее пользуясь возможностями [делегирования событий](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) вешаем всего 1 слушателя на `container`
- Смотрим есть ли класс `fishka` у нажатого элемента, чтобы убедиться, что точно была нажата именно фишка, а не что-то другое, например `row`
- У нажатой фишки берём родителя, а это наш `row`, берём индекс фишки, чтобы значть начало отсчёта и устанавливаем вспомогательные переменные
- Далее объявляем массив всех тех элементов, которым мы потом сменим класс. Сам элемент, сразу кладём в этот массив, т.к. для него класс сменится в любом случае
- Далее если нажатая фишка была справа, то смотрим сколько фишек, которые ещё не на левой стороне, находятся левее её. Записываем их всех в массив и потом всем им добавлем класс `left`
- Если же нажатая фишка была слева, то смотрим сколько фишек, которые ещё не на правой стороне, находятся справа от неё. Записываем их всех в массив и потом у всех удаляем класс `left`

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const rows = container.querySelectorAll('.row');

rows.forEach(r => r.querySelectorAll('.fishka').forEach((el, i) => el.dataset.index = i));

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;

  if (!target.classList.contains('fishka')) return;

  const row = target.parentNode;
  const currentIndex = Number(target.dataset.index);
  const isLeft = target.classList.contains('left');
  const moveElements = [target];
  const [direction, limit] = isLeft ? [1, row.children.length] : [-1, -1];

  for (let i = currentIndex + direction; i !== limit; i += direction) {
    const el = row.children[i];

    if (el.classList.contains('left') === isLeft) {
      moveElements.push(el);
      continue;
    }

    break;
  }

  for (const el of moveElements) el.classList.toggle('left', !isLeft);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #777;
}

section {
  padding-top: 113px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pole {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.fishka {
  overflow: auto;
}

.fishka:hover {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}
```

```html
<section class="pole">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
      <img alt="fishka" class="fishka">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @НатальяЗавороткина Если мой ответ помог вам, то пожалуйста отметье его как принятый, поставив зелёную галочку слева от моего ответа :)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к каждому элементу i-той строки (начиная с 0) id,скажем, "row-ij",где j-номер элемента (тоже с 0).
Тогда получите код:

```
var rows=6,cols=10;//количество строк и столбцов
for(let i=0;i<rows;i++){
for(let j=0;j<cols;j++){
document.getElementById(`row-${i}${j}`).addEventListener("click",function(){
for(let k=j;k<cols;k++){
document.getElementById(`row-${i}${k}`).classList.toggle(`fishka${i}_${k}-final`)
document.getElementById(`row-${i}${k}`).classList.toggle(`fishka${i}_${k}-initial`)
})
}
}
```